# MsSQL Trigger Not running for Multiple Inserts

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, triggers

I have a stored procedure that is taking in an XML string as a parameter. This XML inserts a variable number of records into a table.

The table that it is inserting into however has a trigger set up so that upon each insert, something else happens with another table.

The issue I am facing is that it is treating the XML insert as a single row insert, even if 10 records are inserted through the procedure, the trigger is only ran one time.

Is there a way around this, still using triggers or do I need to go another route?

```
 @departments XML = <departments>
    <department>
        <departmentID>123</departmentID>
    </department>
    <department>
        <departmentID>456</departmentID>
    </department>
 </departments>


 -- Add new department into primary table
INSERT INTO careerpath.LatticeDepartment (LatticeID,DepartmentID,DepartmentOrder)

SELECT @latticeID,
        ParamValues.x1.value('departmentID[1]', 'int'),
        99
FROM @departments.nodes('/departments/department') AS ParamValues(x1)
```

**Table cp.Department has a Trigger**
This only gets ran one time, even if the stored procedure inserts 10 records into `careerpath.LatticeDepartment`.

```
-- Insert statements for trigger here

DECLARE @latticeID int
DECLARE @departmentID INT

SELECT @latticeID = Inserted.LatticeID, @departmentID = Inserted.DepartmentID
FROM Inserted

-- count number of titles
DECLARE @numTitles INT

SELECT @numTitles = COUNT(TitleID)
FROM careerpath.LatticeTitle
WHERE LatticeID = @latticeID

-- check if there are titles with same latticeID
IF @numTitles >= 1
BEGIN

    -- create new boxes for all titleID's with given latticeID and DepartmentID

    INSERT INTO careerpath.Box
    (
        LatticeID,
        DepartmentID,
        TitleID
    )
    SELECT @latticeID,
        @departmentID,
        TitleID
    FROM careerpath.LatticeTitle
    WHERE LatticeID = @latticeID

END
```

Comment: what is tileid? Do you mean count(inserted.titleid)  .FROM inserted.LatticeTitle?

Comment: Because your trigger is tragically flawed. Triggers fire once per operation in sql server, not once per row. When you start using scalar variables inside a trigger it is sign you need to stop and rethink what you are doing. It needs to be written set based to handle multiple rows.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange, thats what I figured. I am working with some legacy code on this project and wanted to see if it was fixable or better to re-write it.

Comment: In  a trigger there are two tables created inserted and deleted. You need to examine these tables to see what was inserted....

Comment: It is fixable. Looks like you could eliminate most of the stuff in there and just make that single insert statement work. Just need to rethink that insert and it should be good to go.